# C# shift an array of byte

Tags: c#, byte, shift

I want to compute this : `tab<<1` with tab an array of byte

I do these few lines but it seems that it does not work. I'm I doing something wrong?

```
byte[] T = new byte[16];


for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) T[i] = (byte)(tab[i] << 1);
```

Comment: *"but it seems that it does not work"*.  What doesn't work? What do you expect, What do you get?

Comment: The first line is not valid C# code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  It looks like you want to left-bit-shift every element in the array by 1, is that correct?

Comment: this won't work because the MSB in each byte gets discarded, when it has to become the LSB of the next byte.
you can use a mask to save the MSB before shifting and then add it to the next byte

Comment: thanks! if I want to save the MSB I need to xor with 0xff ? and then if the MSB is 1 do I have to add 1 to the next byte?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry over the `MSB` of each byte, you can do something like this:

```
var t = new byte[16];

byte carry = 0x0;
for (var i = 15; i >=0 ; i--)
{
    var newcarry = (byte) (t[i] & 0x80);
    t[i] = (byte) (t[i] << 1 + carry);
    carry = newcarry;
}
```

Comment: thanks! but I have a problem with the line: var newcarry = (byte) (t[i] & 0x80); which is : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: yes I see it, but even I write i-- the error is still here :s

Comment: what's the value of i there ?